# Zend Framework - routing same routes to different controller

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-framework-routing

I have two routes and want to match both routes when some parameter exists in request.

**Route 1:**

```
            'companies' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/api/v1/companies[/:id]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => V1\Rest\Controller\CompaniesController::class,
                ]
            ],
            'priority' => 2,
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ],
```

**Route 2:**

```
            'company_members' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/api/v1/companies[/:id][/:members][/:member_id]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => V1\Rest\Controller\CompanyMembersController::class,
                ]
            ],
            'priority' => 2,
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ],
```

I want to use CompanyMembersController when members exists in the request and CompaniesController when members doesnt exists .But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the second route where you defined **members** as a parameter **[/:members]**. You should change this to a **/members**.

I also would recommend to use constraints for your route parameters. Your routes should look like:

```
'companies' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/api/v1/companies[/:id]',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\CompaniesController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],
        'constraints' => [
            'id' => '\d+'
        ]
    ],
    'priority' => 2,
    'may_terminate' => true,
],
'company_members' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/api/v1/companies[/:id]/members[/:member_id]',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\CompanyMembersController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],
        'constraints' => [
            'id' => '\d+',
            'member_id' => '\d+',
        ]
    ],
    'priority' => 2,
    'may_terminate' => true,
],
```

Also you can see the **constraints** to parameters id & member_id to integers.

### References

- [zend mvc routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html)
- [understanding routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html)
- [routing and controllers](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)